# Can I alter multiple illustrator ai-files to svg files and preserve the layers?

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I have multiple .ai-files prepared in adobe illustrator CS3. I would like to transform all of these .ai-files in one go to .svg-files - but preserve the layering I originally had in the .ai-files?

I can easily open my .ai-files in Adobe Illustrator and export them individually from within Adobe Illustrator to an .svg-format. But this will take quite some time to do on more than one hundred .ai-files.

I have no issues opening an .ai-file from a .svg-file reading software, such as InkScape. But I can see that all the layers in the original .ai-files have been fused in to a single layer in InkScape.

I don't want to manually open every single .ai-file from within an .svg-reading software and manually pick and move elements to new layers. This will take an eternity to do on all my .ai-files.
Many of my .ai-files have quite a lot of layers.

I am pretty sure there isn't a question like this on StackFolder. The majority of the questions appear to go in the opposite direction from svg to ai files.
But please redirect me to a different post if I have overlooked something.

Thanks in advance for your help on this

Answer (score 1):

I know it doesn't make much sense to answer after over six years... But anyway. Here is the script that finds all AI files in selected folder and its subfolders and export them in SVG:

```
main();

function main() {
    var folder = Folder.selectDialog('Select folder');
    if (!(folder instanceof Folder)) return;

    var files = get_ai_files(folder, []);
    if (files.length == 0) {
        alert('The folder contains no AI files')
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var doc = app.open(files[i]);
        var file = File(doc.fullName.fsName.replace(/\.ai$/i, '.svg'))
        doc.exportFile(file, ExportType.SVG);
        doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }

    alert('Number of saved SVG files: ' + files.length);
}

function get_ai_files(folder, files_array) {
    var files = folder.getFiles('*');
    if (files.length == 0) return files_array;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if (/.+\.ai$/i.test(file.name)) files_array.push(file);
        if (file instanceof Folder) files_array.concat(get_ai_files(file, files_array));
    }
    return files_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script to open each .ai file and export as svg. [Scripting Guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html)

Would be a pretty simple script if all you need to do is open and export and all your .ai files are in the same folder.